# Is this a Swift bug? Opening a File in a webView

Tags: ios, webview, swift

I am starting working my way through this new language, which I like a lot ... but it seems to to be buggier than I expected.

I took a simple example on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rva9ylPHi2w) of building a webView in the root viewController and loading a webpage.  This example works fine with an external webpage, but not a local file.  I get a blank screen when trying to open a local file.

The code below is for the ViewController.swift file.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var WebView : UIWebView

    var URLPath = ""/files/test.html""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        loadAddressURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadAddressURL() {
        let requestURL = NSURL (string:URLPath)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

        println("the requestURL is: \(requestURL)")

        WebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

}
```

You can see I added a println to show the URL request being used and it appears backward:

With a local file I get "the requestURL is: /files/test.html", which is where I have the sample html file located.

Is their something I did wrong or should I file this with Apple?

Answer (score 3):

This is how i archived to load html from local file

```
 let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
 var url = bundle.URLForResource("yourHTML", withExtension: "html");
 var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
 webContent.loadRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the `NSURL` with that constructor, use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`
instead.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that before and got a very weird path in the println: "the requestURL is: /files/test.html -- file:///".  Notice how the "file///" is inserted after my var is loaded, which of course leaves mw with a blank screen since the path is invalid.

Comment: Yes, that's the way `[NSURL description]` prints it, but that's not what the URL really looks like.

Comment: So it still doesn't work and all I get in the emulator is a blank webView.  Sound like I will start a bug with Apple

Comment: I highly, highly doubt that it's an Apple bug. Put the file in the application's documents dir, and access it there.

Comment: I started with it there and it did not work there either.  I moved to the files directory under the main apps directory, which is where I ultimately want it to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really load a "local file". Instead, make sure your file is added to the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase of your target, and ask the default `NSBundle` for its URL, for example like this:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "html")
```

If the file is located in a project group (yellow icon) the file, you don't have to provide any path information, because the file and not the project group is copied.

If the file is located in a folder reference (blue folder icon), the entire folder is copied to the bundle. In that case use `URLForResource(, withExtension:, subdirectory:)`, or any similar method instead. (Checkout the documentation or the header file of `NSBundle`)

Comment: If I do it that way, how should I include any path information?

Comment: @padapa Oh, sorry, I was guessing you didn't have to (see edits)

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the edits.  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView in Swift language :-

Please update your code and set the URLPath in double quotes like this

```
var URLPath = "/files/test.html"
```

you can also use this code for WebView

```
self.webView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:"https://www.google.com")))
```

Answer (score 1):

***I'm a newbie so don't trust my code***

It seems like it works, however it is making my xCode 6 lag (unusual.) I fallowed the tutorial given by AppleDev/Swift Dive (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rva9ylPHi2w) If you place your index.html file on the index of your app, this is the code to use;

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        loadAddressURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadAddressURL() {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webview.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

The index looks somewhat like this :

```
Folder Project/app/
Folder Project/app/AppDelaget.swift
Folder Project/app/ViewController.swift
Folder Project/app/main.storybord
Folder Project/app/index.html
```