# Load local html into UIWebView using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

This one is driving me crazy early this morning. I want to load some local html into a web view:

```
class PrivacyController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView:UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "privacy.html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

The html file is located in the root folder of my project but is inside a group. The webview is blank for me. Any ideas whats wrong? I am on xcode 6.1 and running this example on my iphone 6.

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591926/is-this-a-swift-bug-opening-a-file-in-a-webview

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To retrieve URLs for application resources, you should use `URLForResource` method of `NSBundle` class.

**Swift 2**

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("privacy", withExtension:"html")
```

**Swift 3**

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "privacy", withExtension: "html")
```

Comment: The catching point is that it has to be "privacy" and not "privacy.html". This was the reason why it was not working for me.

Comment: just to add.. works perfectly fine with Swift 4 and onwards

Answer (score 30):

**Swift 3: type safe**

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Adding webView content
    do {
        guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myFile", ofType: "html")
            else {
                // File Error
                print ("File reading error")
                return
        }

        let contents =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
        let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
    }
    catch {
        print ("File HTML error")
    }
}
```

Keep in mind: NS = Not Swift :]

Comment: Thanks you @Peter Kreinz

Comment: why does it takes a few seconds to load first time?

Answer (score 18):

```
// Point UIWebView
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //load a file
    var testHTML = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("privacy", ofType: "html")
    var contents = NSString(contentsOfFile: testHTML!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    var baseUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: testHTML!) //for load css file

    webView.loadHTMLString(contents, baseURL: baseUrl)

}
```

Comment: Hi I am facing to load nested files of HTML file Like: CSS files in WKWebView. Is this 
for security purpose or anything else?

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 3** with ***3*** lines **:)**

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "privacy", withExtension: "html") {
    webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the local HTML file into your project and name that file as home.html, then create the NSURLRequest using NSURL object. After that passing the request to web view it will load the requested URL into web view and if you are not using storyboard add the uiwebview into view controller view like the below code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("home", withExtension: "html");
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
        myWebView.loadRequest(myRequest);
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
    }
```

For more reference please refer this https://sourcefreeze.com/uiwebview-example-using-swift-in-ios/

Answer (score 9):

**Swift version 2.1**

this case also include Encoding

```
// load HTML String with Encoding
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("policy", ofType: "html")
do {
    let fileHtml = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    webView.loadHTMLString(fileHtml as String, baseURL: nil)
}
catch {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is worked for me:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fineName", ofType: "html")!)))

}
```

Added `App Transport Security Settings` with `Dictionary` type in **info.plist** file. Also added sub key `Allow Arbitrary Loads` for **App Transport Security Settings** with type `Boolean` and value `YES`.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcVv1N1hReQ) is tutorial.

***EDITED***

For Swift 3 (Xcode 8)

```
mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test/index", ofType: "html")!)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is succinct version for **Swift 4**

1) Add import `import WebKit`

2) Add `WebKit.framework` in your project

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

if let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FILE_NAME", withExtension: "html") {
  let request = NSURLRequest(url: filePath)
  webView.load(request as URLRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load html string or local html file in UIWebView.

HTML string:

```
func loadHtmlCode() {
    let htmlCode = "<html><head><title>Wonderful web</title></head> <body><p>wonderful web. loading html code in <strong>UIWebView</strong></></body>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlCode, baseURL: nil)
}
```

HTML file:

```
func loadHtmlFile() {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("contactus", withExtension:"html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Details can be found here: 
http://webindream.com/load-html-uiwebview-using-swift/

Comment: how to show image in loadHtmlCode() because i tried but image is empty showing @farhad rubel

Comment: i tried like this  let htmlCode = "<html><head><title>Wonderful web</title></head> <body bgcolor= orange><p>wonderful web. loading html code in <strong>UIWebView</strong></p><p><img src=chania.jpg width=200 height=200></p></></body>"

Answer (score 2):

For swift 3 Use this:

```
do
    {
        let testHTML = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "about", ofType: "html")
        let contents =  try NSString(contentsOfFile: testHTML!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let baseUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: testHTML!) //for load css file

        mWebView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl as URL)
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.1, WKWebView load HTML from file. UIWebView is deprecated.

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView.

```
import WebKit

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "document_terms_of_use", withExtension: "html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: localFilePath!)
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 4.2 & 5:

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768))
let url = URL(string: PERS_Path)
webView?.navigationDelegate = self
webView?.uiDelegate = self
webView!.loadFileURL(url!, allowingReadAccessTo: url!)
self.view. addSubview(webView)
```

don't forget to add this `WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

@IBOutlet weak var webViewer: UIWebView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let localfilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "homeInfo", withExtension: "html");
    let myRequest = NSURLRequest(url: localfilePath!);
    webViewer.loadRequest(myRequest as URLRequest);
    self.view.addSubview(webViewer)
}
```