# Path to local files for Webview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

Tried to make first app in Xcode: took my Web App folder and tried to implement it to XCode project with WebView. But got no success - always blank screen in simulator...

I started new project, created `WebView` and implement a folder with my Web App through `File` -> `Add files to "MyProject"` with option set to copy files and set url to local `index.html` in view controller. What am I doing wrong?

Project Structure:

```
-dist
--index.html
--scriptsbundle.js
--img
---myimages.png

-MyProject

-MyProject.xcodeproj

-MyProjectTests

-MyProjectUITests
```

My `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var Webview: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: Bundle.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory:"../dist")!)
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)

        Webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}
```

Comment: have you tried solutions provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift

Comment: Yep, thank you. But after some refactor cause of Swift version thought. Now all works, except all images in `img` folder (works only one svg image, implemented in css-style) :(

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment, that Amod Gokhale wrote, another article saved my life, but after a bit refactor:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType:"html")
let url = NSURL(string: path!)
let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
```