# How to open local html file on Safari?

Tags: html, ios, swift, safari, swift3

I want to open a local html file on `Safari` integration on my `Swift 3` application.

I know how to do this with an url. This is the code that I use to do that:

```
let encodedString = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: encodedString!) as! URL)
self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I am not able to do the same with a local file. I have copied my html file on my project and I can see it on the directories tree but I am not able to make it to work. I have looked at [Load local html into UIWebView using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift) for reference.

How can I load a local html file into Safari integration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share your code to display a local file in safari (the code snippet you shared currently is not). And also paste the console error output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*You can't do it using [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)*

> ***From Apple Documentation:***

***1. Choosing the Best Web Viewing Class***

*If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet, use the [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) class. If your app customizes, interacts with, or controls the display of web content, use the [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) class.*

***2. if you look at declaration of [init](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller/1621222-init)***

```
convenience init(url URL: URL)
```

*`url:` The URL to navigate to. The URL must use the `http` or `https` scheme.*

***Using Webkit or WebView***

***helloAshok.html***

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <h2> Welcome ASHOK</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

***ViewContrller.swift***

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "helloAshok", withExtension: "html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: localFilePath!)
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]