# How do I open a "file:///" link in "Safari" on "iOS" using "Swift"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safari

I'm developing an iOS app that needs to be able to tell Safari to load a local HTML file using a `file:///` URL, how can I achieve this?

To clarify further it has to be in Safari not a webview and the file is accessible...

Comment: Hi Lil, Please refer attached link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450130/8259188

Comment: The file is likely sandboxed and not accessible. Depending what it is, you could always run a local web server in your app which Safari can access.