# Loading a Local HTML file in UIWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, swift2

I am having trouble loading a local HTML file. Here is my code. please help.

```
let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index2", ofType: "html")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
Webview.loadRequest(request)
```

by use the following code. I have manage to load the html file but it doesn't load up the CSS!

let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index1", ofType: "html")
        let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        GSFWebView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load local html file into UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview)

Comment: [Edit] your question with details about your trouble. The code you posted probably won't even compile. Start with the those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write this code inside your ViewDidLoad i have added url of this page as example, just replace it with yours. On storyboard you don't need to do anything, if you have any extra view added on you view controller as container for website then replace `self.view` in my code with your view.

```
    let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    //add your url on line below
    myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift")!))
    self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
```

And if you want to load page from local file, you can do it by defining url this way.

**Swift 2**

```
  let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("webFileName", withExtension:"html")
```

**Swift 3**

```
  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "webFileName", withExtension: "html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I only had to add this code to the viewDidLoad method:

1- First of all, you have to get the local URL from the Bundle. (previously, I added the index.html file to the project, copying when asked)

2- Then you have to create the request URL to be loaded from the webView.

3- After all, add the new webView created as a subView from the main view.

That worked for me.

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html"){// 1st step
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)

        let request = URLRequest(url: url as URL) // 2nd step
        webView.load(request)
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView) // 3rd step
}
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've modified my response adding some explanation.