# Webview application in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to load an HTML page that is located in my local directory. It shows me this error 
"failed to load: data/Anctors.json"
Also, this page works fine on Firefox but not working on Google Chrome.
My code:

```
var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
    let url = URL(string: "file:///Users/rashid/Documents/Developers/Swift/www/index.html")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
    toolbarItems = [refresh]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    title = webView.title
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load local html into UIWebView using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Bundle.main.url(forResource: <#T##String?#>, withExtension: <#T##String?#>)` method to load resources from within the app
Refer the following link for more detailed answer (Possible Duplicate)

[[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift)

Comment: "file:///Users/rashid/Documents/Developers/Swift/www/index.html"
This is my file url path

Comment: This is my Absolute path where i have all the html files and folders

Comment: Try this - Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")

Comment: Drag and drop the index.html below the Project in Xcode and check Copy item if needed and try the same code

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code for allow content from document directory:

```
self.webView.loadFileURL( htmlfilePath, allowingReadAccessTo: documentDirUrl)
```

and make sure your html file and other content both are in same directory.