# How to display links and images from an HTML String

Tags: html, ios, swift

I have a string that contains `HTML` code. What is the best way to display that (it contains images), also I want to make links in that tappable (open in `Safari`)

I have tried String extension that gives me `NSAttributedString` from `HTML`, but the image is only partially shown and links are not tappable.

```
let text = htmlString.attributedString(withRegularFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), andBoldFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16))

extension String {

    func attributedString(withRegularFont regularFont: UIFont, andBoldFont boldFont: UIFont, textColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }
        do {
            attributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
            attributedString.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, in: range, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { value, range, _ in
            let currentFont: UIFont = value as! UIFont
            var replacementFont: UIFont? = nil

            if currentFont.fontName.contains("bold") || currentFont.fontName.contains("Semibold") {
                replacementFont = boldFont
            } else {
                replacementFont = regularFont
            }

            let replacementAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:replacementFont!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor]
            attributedString.addAttributes(replacementAttribute, range: range)
        } catch let e {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

It shows me the `HTML` inside the `UILabel` but I am not able to tap on links and images are cropped respective to device width.

Comment: use webview top of label make sure you html text to label . Then all your functionalities will work without any issue

Comment: in webview i have tried, but i am not able to fix its height, i dont want inline scroll

Comment: You can make `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false`

Comment: it works, but i dont want the webview to zoom and also i dont want inline scroll of webView instead i want height of that, because i am using it under tableview cell, which in under collection view

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best option is to save this html string as a file and then load this file using web view.
check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift)

Comment: the html content is dynamic, its coming from api and i need to show that inside a collectionview that contains a tableview inside its cell